# different shell behaviour: bash omits newline, zsh keeps it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, zsh

I have a script which searches source files that contain a "TODO"
note inside the comments. Furthermore I use a concatenation of `grep`, `git blame`, `uniq` and `sort` to get
the list ordered by the person who wrote the TODO comment.

The following works fine in bash and zsh:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $(grep -r -i "todo" apps/business | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://' | sed 's/\#//') 
do
git blame $FILE | grep -i "todo"
done | sort -k2 | uniq
```

Now I want to count all the entries. Instead of calling the (time expensive)
`grep`/`git blame` again, I want to save everything into `$MATCHES` to count it
without evaluating it again.

```
MATCHES=$(for FILE in $(grep -r -i "todo" apps/business | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://' | sed 's/\#//') 
do
    git blame $FILE | grep -i "todo"
done | sort -k2 | uniq)

echo $MATCHES
```

That's where I experience different behaviour in bash/zsh:

**zsh:** Returns the same as the first script (as expected)

**bash:** Ignores the newlines of git blame, puts everything on one line. `wc -l` counts 1 line.

What am I missing here? Why is bash behaving differently here?
And how do I get bash to not-ignore the newline?

Comment: Try `echo "$MATCHES"`. Without the quotes bash will parse the variable into words based on the value of `IFS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` doesn't perform word-splitting on the unquoted parameter expansion `$MATCH` by default. Use `echo "$MATCHES" | wc -l`, and `bash` should work as well.

Note this is the wrong way to iterate over the output of a command; use a `while` loop and the `read` command instead.

```
grep -ri "todo" apps/business | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/://' -e 's/\#//' |
  while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    git blame "$FILE" | grep -i todo
  done | sort -k2 | uniq
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain why `for` is the wrong way while `while` with `read` is better? Thank you!